# Overflow property working in JSfiddle but not on chrome/safari

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm struggling with the horizontal overflow-property for a div-box. The code doesn't work on safari & chrome, but does work when I enter it in a JSfiddle...

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```css
#box {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#box1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: pink;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#box2 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 380px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
 <div id="box1">
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: I want to use it for my music website. The black boxes (#box2) will be filled with artwork and track details.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get your problem, i get the same result in chrome, firefox, IE and edge.

**First**

```
#box {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This doesn't work if you want to hide boxes. Apply this style on #box1 instead and remove the existing overflow style.

```
#box1 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Second**

You have overflow properties on two elements:

```
#box {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and

```
#box1 {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Maybe this is causing the problem, remove one overflow style and keep the other overflow style.

Comment: I removed the #box overflow style, but the box still doesn't scroll horizontal... Strange that the code does work for you on chrome, etc.

Comment: Maybe delete your browser cache? ( Chrome: [CTRL] + [SHIFT] + R )